# $getRecord does not result in a $save method being available in Angular Fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using Firebase and AngularFire to try to keep my dat synced. My code is:

```
var questionsRef, ref, ref1;

questionsRef = fbase.child("questions").orderByChild("subject").equalTo("english");

$scope.questions = $firebaseArray(questionsRef);

$scope.questions.$loaded().then(function() {
  if ($stateParams.id) {
    $scope.currentQuestion = $scope.questions.$getRecord($stateParams.id);
    return console.log($scope.currentQuestion);
  } else {
    return $scope.currentQuestion = {
      answers: []
    };
  }
});

$scope.currentQuestion.editedByUserId = (ref = auth.$getAuth()) != null ? (ref1 = ref.auth) != null ? ref1.uid : void 0 : void 0;

$scope.currentQuestion.editedOn = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

$scope.currentQuestion.$save();
```

This **should** save the updates to the `currentQuestion` (based on the form in HTML via `ng-model`), but instead I get `Error: $scope.currentQuestion.$save is not a function. (In '$scope.currentQuestion.$save()', '$scope.currentQuestion.$save' is undefined)`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh - that was silly. Turns out I was using it wrong. I need to do

`$scope.questions.$save($scope.currentQuestion)`

Since the`$save` is on the `questions` array